# Use value of dropdown in some other controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have two drop downs and i want to use the selected option in some other controller.
i.e I am having 2 offices in the drop down and i am selecting office_1 ,I want to use the value(i.e office_1)  in some other controller where I could implement a check condition.How can i Link the two controllers.

here is my drop down code

```
<div class="col-xs-12">

<div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-1 ">
    <h5>Select the System:</h5>


    <select id="repeatSystem" ng-model="selectedSystem" style="width: 100%">
        <option ng-repeat="(key,value) in systems" value="{{key}}">{{key}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-1">
    <h5>Select the Office:</h5>

    <select id="repeatOffice" ng-model="selectedState" style="width: 100%">
        <option ng-repeat="system in systems[selectedSystem]" value="state">{{system}}</option>
    </select>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a service to communicate the selected value between the two controllers:

```
module.factory('SharingService',function(){
  var selectedValue;  
  return{
     setValue:function(value){
                  selectedValue=value;
              },
     getValue:function(){
                 return selectedValue;
              }
  }
}
```

Use a watcher in one of the controllers to set the value;

```
module.controller('Controller1',function($scope,SharingService){

$scope.$watch('selectedOffice',function(newVal){
      SharingService.setValue(newVal);
  })


});
```

Get it in another controller using `SharingService.getValue` method.

Alternatives:

1.You can also use event broadcasting to communicate the data between two controllers.

2.If the controllers are nested, the model value from parent can be directly accessed from child controller.